# ubuntu 14.04 installation in virtual box very slow

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, virtualbox

I am a newbie to the Unix OS , I was advised to start working on Ubuntu and due to some restrictions I had to install it on Oracle Virtual Box. I gave it the right amount of RAM but it's still not usable , it's very slow.  Do you kow any way to fix this ?

Comment: Have you considered running it on bare metal? VM's are great for experimenting but you'll never get max performance that way...

Answer (score 0):

well, have you thought of the possibility that you are running it in an emulator/ virtual box? When you run an Operating System in a virtual box, you are cutting your system's performance in half. So, when you said that you added the right amount of ram, you ought to have doubled the recommended RAM. The virtual box consumes more ram than what is recommended. it also depends on your processor. i ran a virtual box of my own and the system registered that i was using a single-core processor and 2 GB of RAM when I actually had a Dual-core and 4 GB of RAM. The best option is to upgrade your hardware or just install Ubuntu alongside Windows/ Mac OSx. You could also see about partitioning your HDD and just install Ubuntu by itself (dual-boot). You would still be able to work on ubuntu, as far as programming and what not, from the primary Operating System. Ubuntu provides free ubuntu console editors for free. Running in Bare-metal mode is also optional, but you still may not get maximum performance from your system.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adjusting the settings in virtual box?

[image: boxsettings]